# How to access default resource from other assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, resources

I have default resource file (*.resx) compiled in other assembly (just as default `Properties.Resources`), this assembly referenced by `Assembly` object. How can I access specific resource object inside it?

I tried:

```
public static class Resource
{
    public static T Get<T>(Assembly assembly, string name)
    {
        ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager(assembly.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources", assembly);
        return (T)manager.GetObject(name);
    }
}
```

This throws `MissingManifestResourceException` and debugger shows that through `manager` is initialized as `ResourceManager` instance, the `manager.ResourceSet` is empty.

Comment: I have just tested your code with a test project. It works just fine. Have you specified the resources access modifier as `public` ?

Comment: @PonasJustas
Yes, I did. I debug it further and found out that `assembly.GetName().Name` returns executable name, not namespace. So if you have spaces in executable name they will not be canonized into underscores... But doing this manually is a bit too hacky for me

Comment: Previously i have tested with a simple assembly without spaces. Just did a new test with an assembly that contains spaces. So the assembly itself does not know about the default namespace. However types know what is the namespace they belong to. Try this: `new System.Resources.ResourceManager(assembly.DefinedTypes.First(x => x.Name == "Resources").FullName, assembly);` . Of course, ideally you should make more checks to make it fool proof, but this should put you on a correct track.

Comment: @PonasJustas Nice! Can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the assembly itself does not know about the default namespace. However types know what is the namespace they belong to. Try this:
`new System.Resources.ResourceManager(assembly.DefinedTypes.First(x => x.Name == "Resources").FullName, assembly);`
Of course, ideally you should make more checks to make it fool proof, but this should put you on a correct track